# JS, the problem of making a card rotation sound when you click on the green space underneath the card while it is turned behind its back

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

```
<html>  
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css"> 
  <title>Game Cards App</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/entertainment-events-hobbies/24/card-game-cards-hold-512.png">
  

  
<style>
#main-content {
  display: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(7, 50, 22, 255) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 255) 100%);
  animation: shine 4s linear infinite;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Lato";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.card {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(33.33% - 30px + 9.999px);
  height: 340px;
  margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
  perspective: 1000;
 
}
.card:first-child .card__front {
  background:#5271C2;
}

.card__front img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.card:first-child .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(52, 78, 147, 0.8)
}
.card:nth-child(2) .card__front {
  background:#35a541;
}
.card:nth-child(2) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(34, 107, 42, 0.8);
}
.card:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.card:nth-child(3) .card__front {
  background: #bdb235;
}
.card:nth-child(3) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(129, 122, 36, 0.8);
}
.card:nth-child(4) .card__front {
  background: #db6623;
}
.card:nth-child(4) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(153, 71, 24, 0.8);
}
.card:nth-child(5) .card__front {
  background: #3e5eb3;
}
.card:nth-child(5) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(42, 64, 122, 0.8);
}
.card:nth-child(6) .card__front {
  background: #aa9e5c;
}
.card:nth-child(6) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(122, 113, 64, 0.8);
}
.card:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.card__flipper {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  border: 3.5px solid rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.6); 
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5), transparent, rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5)); 
}
.card__front, .card__back {
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 340px;
}
.card__front {
  transform: rotateY(0);
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card__back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.1);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #483D8B, #301934, #483D8B, #301934);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  
}
.card__back span {
  font-weight: bold; 
  color: white; /* Beyaz renk */
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.card__name {
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 0.9;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.card__name span {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.card__num {
  font-size: 100px;
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
  font-weight: 700;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .card__num {
    font-size: 70px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 290px;
    margin-right: 0;
    float: none;
  }
  .card .card__front,
  .card .card__back {
    height: 290px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

/* Demo */
main {
  text-align: center;
}
main h1, main p {
  margin: 0 0 12px 0;
}
main h1 {
  margin-top: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.fa-github {
  color: white; 
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 8px; 
}

.tm-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
 
}

.tm-letter {
 
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:30px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(0);
  animation: letter-animation 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes letter-animation {
  0%, 100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  10%, 40%, 60%, 90% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  20%, 80% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

#m-letter {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
}

a::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%; 
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
    width: 50px;
    height: 45px;
   
    
    border-radius: 50%; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 4px rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.8); 
    filter: blur(4px) brightness(1.5); 
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease;
  
    z-index: -1;
}

a:hover::before {
    opacity: 1;
  
}


body.hoverEffect {
      background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #000000, #000033, #000066, #1a1a1a);
}

#gameCard { 
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 
    0 0 50px 10px #FFD700,  
    0 0 100px 20px #0000FF,
    0 0 150px 30px #000033; 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);  
    color:#FFD700;   
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid #FFD700; 

#gameCardLink span {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-right: 5px; 
  font-weight: bold; 
}

#gameCardLink span:last-child {
  font-size: 0.79em;
  vertical-align: super; 
  opacity: 0.9;
  font-weight: bold; 
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
}


#loading-animation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://wallpapercrafter.com/desktop1/516243-black-holes-blue-black-holes-space-1080P.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover ;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 9999;
 }

.loader {

  border-top: 9px solid #00a2ed;
  border-radius: 80%;
  width: 12vw;
  height: 12vw; 
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite; 
  position: absolute;
  left: 44%; /
  top: 46%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg); 
  }

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

</style>
   
</head>


<body>

<div id="loading-animation">
  <div class="loader"></div>
</div>

<div id="main-content">

  <div class="tm-container">
    <div class="tm-letter" id="t-letter">T</div>
    <div class="tm-letter" id="m-letter">M</div>
  </div>


<audio id="flipSound" preload="auto">
  <source src="https://cdn.freesound.org/previews/321/321114_2776777-lq.ogg" type="audio/wav">
</audio>



<main>
   <div id="gameCardLink">
      <span>G</span>
      <span>a</span>
      <span>m</span>
      <span>e</span>
      <span> </span> 
      <span> </span>
      <span>C</span>
      <span> </span>
      <span>a</span>
      <span> </span>
      <span>r</span>
      <span> </span>
      <span>d</span>
      <span> </span>
      <span>s</span>
      <span>®</span> 
   </div>
  <p><a href="https://github.com/murattasci06"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></p>
</main>


<ul>
  <li class="card" >
    <div class="card__flipper">
      <div class="card__front">
        <img src="https://gecbunlari.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Spiderman-No-Way-Home.jpg" alt="Spiderman">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Marvel</span><br>Spiderman</p>
        <p class="card__num">1</p>
      </div>
  
      
      <iframe class="frame" 
      width="225"
      height="340"
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JfVOs4VSpmA?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
      title="YouTube video player"
      frameborder="0"
      allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
      allowfullscreen
      ></iframe>

      
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
        <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#514d9b" stroke-width="35"  />
        <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
         <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
        <span>1.89 Bil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
 
 
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
         <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1e/f1/3d/1ef13dfa4b7b8c131302e242d1ec48d7.jpg" alt="Batman">
         <p class="card__name"><span>DC</span><br>Batman</p>
        <p class="card__num">2</p>
      </div>
      
        <iframe class="frame" 
        width="225"
        height="340"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mqqft2x_Aa4?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>

      
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#35a541" stroke-width="35"/>
          <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
        <span>771 Mil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp12279011.jpg" alt="Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol_3">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Marvel</span><br>Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol_3</p>
        <p class="card__num">3</p>
        </div>
        <iframe class="frame" 
        width="225"
        height="340"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/u3V5KDHRQvk?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
        
     
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#bdb235" stroke-width="35"/>
         <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
        <span>845.4 Mil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
   
  
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
       <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/8940499.jpg" alt="Shazam">
        <p class="card__name"><span>DC</span><br>Shazam2</p>
        <p class="card__num">4</p>
        </div>
        <iframe class="frame" 
        width="225"
        height="340"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AIc671o9yCI?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
        
        
     
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#db6623" stroke-width="35"/>
         <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
        <span>462.5 Mil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <img src="https://images2.alphacoders.com/131/1316679.jpeg" alt="Flash">
        <p class="card__name"><span>DC</span><br>Flash</p>
        <p class="card__num">5</p>
        </div>
        <iframe class="frame" 
        width="225"
        height="340"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hebWYacbdvc?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
        
        
     
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#3e5eb3" stroke-width="35"/>
          <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
        <span>560.2 Mil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
 
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <img src=" https://images3.alphacoders.com/121/1213553.jpg" alt="Dr_Strange_2">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Marvel</span><br>Dr_Strange_2</p>
        <p class="card__num">6</p>
         </div>
        <iframe class="frame" 
        width="225"
        height="340"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aWzlQ2N6qqg?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
        
      
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#aa9e5c" stroke-width="35"/>
          <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
        <span>955.8 Mil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

</body>


<script>
var Flipper = (function() {
  var card = $('.card');
  var flipper = card.find('.card__flipper');
  var win = $(window);
  
  var flip = function() {
    var thisCard = $(this);
    var thisFlipper = thisCard.find('.card__flipper');
    var offset = thisCard.offset();
    var xc = win.width() / 2;
    var yc = win.height() / 2;
    var docScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
    var cardW = thisCard.outerWidth() / 2;
    var cardH = thisCard.height() / 2;

    var transX = xc - offset.left - cardW;
    var transY = docScroll + yc - offset.top - cardH;
//     if (offset.top > card.height()) transY = docScroll - offset.top + cardH;
    if (win.width() <= 700) transY = 0;
    
    if (card.hasClass('active')) unflip();
        
    thisCard.css({'z-index': '3'}).addClass('active');
    
    thisFlipper.css({
      'transform': 'translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px, 0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px, 0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1)',
      '-ms-transform': 'translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px, 0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1)'
    }).addClass('active');
    
    
    return false;
  };
  
  var unflip = function(e) {
    card.css({'z-index': '1'}).removeClass('active');
    flipper.css({
      'transform': 'none',
      '-webkit-transform': 'none',
      '-ms-transform': 'none'
    }).removeClass('active');
  };
  
  var bindActions = function() {
    card.on('click', flip);
    win.on('click', unflip);
  }
  
  var init = function() {
    bindActions();
  };
  
  return {
    init: init
  };
  
}());
Flipper.init();
  
</script>



<script>
<!-- HOOVER FOR TRAILER -->

let hoverTimeout;

$('.card').hover(function() {
    const currentCard = $(this); // Store the current card element in a variable

    hoverTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        currentCard.find('.card__front').hide();
        currentCard.find('.iframe').show();
        var src = currentCard.find('.iframe').attr("src");
        currentCard.find('.iframe').attr("src", src);

        // Add fullscreen functionality
        currentCard.find('.iframe').on('click', function() {
            $(this).requestFullscreen();
        });

    }, 5000); // 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds)

}, function() {
    clearTimeout(hoverTimeout); // Clear the timeout to prevent actions if the user moves away before 5 seconds

    $(this).find('.card__front').show();
    $(this).find('.iframe').hide();
    var src = $(this).find('.iframe').attr("src");
    $(this).find('.iframe').attr("src", src.replace('?autoplay=1', ''));
});

</script>


<script>
var cardFlags = {};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var flipSound = document.getElementById("flipSound");
  
  $(".card__front").click(function() {
    flipSound.currentTime = 0;
    flipSound.play();
  });

  
  $(".card").click(function() {
    var card = $(this);
    var cardId = card.find(".card__num").text();
    console.log(cardId);
   
    
    // Check if the card is not already flipping to avoid multiple flips
    if (!card.hasClass('flipping')) {
      card.addClass('flipping');

      // Check if the front side is facing the viewer
      if (!card.hasClass("flipped")) {
       
        console.log("is card flag true or false", cardId);

        if (!cardFlags[cardId]) {
          startAnimation(div); 
          console.log("started");
          cardFlags[cardId] = true; 
          card.addClass("flipped");
        }
        
        // Adding canvas to back-side 
        var div = document.querySelector('.flipped .card__flipper.active .card__back');
        var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('p5Canvas')[0];
        if (div && canvas) {
          div.appendChild(canvas);
          canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
        }
      } else {
       
        console.log("stopped");
        card.removeClass("flipped");
        flipSound.play(); 
      }

      setTimeout(function() {
        card.removeClass('flipping');
      }, 1000); // Adjust the timeout to match your animation duration
    }
  });

  // Prevent sound on back side click
  $(".card__back").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});

</script>


<script>
    // Body's hoover effect
 
</script>


<script>

// Portal effect

</script>


<script>

  function hideLoadingAnimation() {
  console.log("Yükleme animasyonu gizleniyor, ana içerik gösteriliyor");
  var loadingAnimation = document.getElementById("loading-animation");
  var mainContent = document.getElementById("main-content");
  loadingAnimation.style.display = "none";
  mainContent.style.display = "block";
}
window.onload = function() {
  console.log("Sayfa tamamen yüklendi");
  hideLoadingAnimation();
};

</script>
</html>
```

**The link including full code:**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OVCaKDnXj-TrPMTFHWDvF-QzLsWB6OKG/view?usp=drive_link

Hello friends, While the cards are turned to their back side, when you first click with the left mouse button on the green space behind them, the sound assigned to turn the card back is heard. Normally this sound shouldn't be heard here. This sound does not appear on subsequent clicks. In the code:

```
$(".card__front").click(function() {
    flipSound.currentTime = 0;
    flipSound.play();
  });
```

I am stating this situation, but I could not figure out why it is working incorrectly?

I was hoping that the sound of the card rotating would only be heard when the card was rotating to the back. I probably have a mistake that experienced people can easily notice.

[image]

Comment: Apart from the sound error, I found another error: the sizes of elements changes randomized: https://imgur.com/a/KmoQKBW

Comment: @adampweb
I had trimmed the code, but now I shared the whole thing in the issue. Unfortunately, I have some bugs, such as when you play a video on the cards, the progress stays in the same place on all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**flipSound.play() >> it should have been included below** (The part that still works when the card is returned)

```
if (div && canvas) {
              div.appendChild(canvas);
              canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
            }
          } else {
           
            console.log("stopped");
            card.removeClass("flipped");
          
          }
```